# .4byte assembly directive usage

Tags: assembly, gnu-assembler, powerpc

When I compile a C file I got below line in temporary S file :

```
.4byte  .Letext0-.Ltext0
```

what does it mean? I understand that ".4byte" directive will reserve 4 consecutive bytes in memory, but what does ".Letext0-.Ltext0" mean?  I am so confused and not able to find something help online. Thank you so much!

Comment: Subtracting two labels gives a number, the distance in bytes between them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Subtracting two labels gives a number, the distance in bytes between them.

`etext` is a symbol used by the linker to indicate the end of the *text section*
`text` indicates the start of the *text section*.

The *text section* tends to be the actual binary program code itself. Although it may also include static data.

This instruction is storing the size of the *text section* (or the program code) in a 32-bit integer.

Comment: What sections does the text segment officially include, for these labels?  I guess not `.rodata` in modern versions of Binutils that link it into its own segment (so it can be read-only *without* exec).  But besides the `.text` section itself, maybe also `.plt` and `.init`?  According to `readelf -a /bin/ls`, there's a segment that includes `.init .plt .text .fini` sections. I guess I'm a bit surprised there's a symbol for the text *segment* instead of just the text *section*, and wondering if perhaps you meant section.

Comment: Yes, I do indeed mean "section" not "segment" - Answer edited.